# Firebase function api call working on emulator but not in production

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to load data in to Firestore using firebase functions from the function storeCategories(), it currently just runs on start but I plan to schedule it once I have it working.

This function works fine on the emulators but in production I'm getting the either 'socket hang up' or 'Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established'

storeTrending() works fine so I'm not sure what is causing it.

```
/** @format */
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const cors = require("cors");
const express = require("express");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const apiKey = functions.config().tmdbapi.key;

const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

var app = express();

app.use(cors());

const storeCategories = async () => {
    try {
        // GET CATEGORY IDS
        const categoriesIDRes = await fetch(
            `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=${apiKey}`
        );
        const categoriesInfo = await categoriesIDRes.json();

        // CREATE CATEGORY API LINKS
        const categoriesURLs = categoriesInfo.genres.map(
            (el) =>
                `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=${apiKey}&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=true&include_video=true&page=1&with_genres=${el.id}&with_watch_monetization_types=flatrate`
        );

        // RETRIEVE POPULAR FILMS FROM EACH CATEGORY
        const categoriesRes = await Promise.all(
            categoriesURLs.map((el) => fetch(el))
        );
        const data = await Promise.all(
            categoriesRes.map((el) => el.json())
        );

        const batch = db.batch();

        // WRITE TO FIRESTORE FOR FASTER INITIAL LOAD
        data.forEach((category, idx) => {
            const ref = db
                .collection("categories")
                .doc(categoriesInfo.genres[idx].name);

            batch.set(ref, category);
        });
        const categoriesInfoRef = db.collection("categoryIDs").doc("IDs");

        batch.set(categoriesInfoRef, categoriesInfo);

        return batch.commit();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
};

storeCategories();

const storeTrending = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch(
            `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/week?api_key=${apiKey}`
        );

        const data = await res.json();

        db.collection("categories").doc("trending").set(data);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
};

storeTrending();
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: screenshot of the error
[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of error?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Yep I've just edited with a screenshot

Comment: My guess is something to do with cors. Check if theres a cors whitelist for the API or try requesting with a separate backend maybe?

Comment: @infecting as far as I know only browsers follow CORS.

Comment: Have you enabled billing on that project? Third-party network requests are blocked unless you are on a paid plan.

Comment: In addition, you haven't included the function that is invoked. This suggests that you aren't managing the function lifecycle correctly and the function is being throttled/shut down before any "work" can be done. See the [docs here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/tips#do_not_start_background_activities). Importantly, this throttling/lifecycle management is **not** emulated locally - just because it works in the emulator doesn't mean it will deployed. You also have a number of "floating" promises that won't have their errors handled correctly.

Comment: @samthecodingman Billing is enabled but I think you're correct on that second point, I've done a bit of reading and I think the functions were being 'cleaned up' before they can finish executing. I think this is because they aren't inside an actual cloud function? They are currently just being invoked directly inside the index.js file. I ran them using a scheduled cloud function and it worked! Thanks for your help.